# running mysql scripts from windows 7 batch files

Tags: mysql, batch-file

Can someone show me how to successfully run the batch file below from the windows cmd command prompt?  I need to perform operations on a MySQL database installed in my computer.  Here is the batch file:

```
::
:: Database connection parameters
:: Please edit these variables to reflect your environment
::
set MYSQL_HOME="C:\pathto\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld"
set user=root 
set password=mypassword 
set host_name=localhost
set db_name=mydatabase 
set max_error_count=0 

 ATTRIB +R %logfile%   

echo ----------------------------------------echo Starting ...
echo ----------------------------------------
echo. %MYSQL_HOME%\bin\mysql -u %user%  -p%password% -h%host_name% --local-infile=1 %db_name% < Table_scripts_mysql_rxn.sql  >> mysql.log 2>&1

 %MYSQL_HOME%\bin\mysql -u %user%  -p%password% -h%host_name%  --local-infile=1 %db_name% < Load_scripts_mysql_rxn_win.sql >> mysql.log 2>&1

echo
echo ----------------------------------------
echo Finished
echo ----------------------------------------
```

But I am getting access denied messages, as indicated by the following history from the command line:

```
C:\mypath>Populate_mysql_rxn
C:\mypath>set MYSQL_HOME="C:\mypath\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
C:\mypath>set user=root
C:\mypath>set password=mypassword
C:\mypath>set host_name=localhost
C:\mypath>set db_name=mydatabase
C:\mypath>set max_error_count=0
C:\mypath>ATTRIB +R
C:\mypath>echo ----------------------------------------echo Starting ...
----------------------------------------echo Starting ...
C:\mypath>echo ----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
C:\mypath>echo.
C:\mypath>"C:\mypath\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"\bin\mysql -u root   -pmypassword
-hlocalhost  --local-infile=1 mydatabase   0<Table_scripts_mysql_rxn.sql 1>>mysql.log 2>&1
Access is denied.

C:\mypath>"C:\mypath\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"\bin\mysql -u root   -pmypassword
-hlocalhost   --local-infile=1 mydatabase   0<Load_scripts_mysql_rxn_win.sql 1>>mysql.log 2>&1
Access is denied.

C:\mypath>echo
ECHO is on.
C:\mypath>echo ----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
C:\mypath>echo Finished
Finished
C:\mypath>echo ----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
C:\mypath>
```

Comment: i think you should try to open your batch file with a text editor like notepad++ and you will be able to remove line breaks or other special characters

Comment: Use Notepad instead. It's installed on every Windows system since Win 3.x, so you have it for sure. Just right-click the batch file and choose 'Edit' from the context menu.

Comment: Service started? Credentials correct? Firewall? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors in that file...  looks like a corrupt copy&paste example.
First.. I recommend to start the `Populate_mysql_rxn2.bat`file with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then, your address var end's up with: `...\bin\mysqld` and when you call the var, you add `%MYSQL_HOME%\bin\mysql` 
That give you the first error...

The consecutive errors `is not recognized as an internal or external command` are for the reason already gave..
you could concatenate if you don't now how to do it in multiple lines
i.e

```
set user=root && set password=mypassword && set allthis=sameline
```

finally.. the `Access is denied.` is obvius... `mysql` address is wrong, and the connection var are not properly set... ***plus***:

```
... -p%password% -h%host_name% ...
```

must be:

```
... -p %password% -h %host_name% ...
```

Now.. for the edition problems you have..  try to start a **`completly new file`** and write yourself the code, don't copy & paste... many web sites have symbols that are copied and may corrupt your file. (your code is fully spaced)

*Note: I din't check your code actually work.. just see and try to correct some visible mistakes in your example code*

Have to end up with something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set MYSQL_HOME="C:\pathto\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql"
set user=root
set password=mypassword
set host_name=localhost
set db_name=mydatabase
set max_error_count=0

ATTRIB +R %logfile%

echo ----------------------------------------
echo Starting
echo ----------------------------------------

%MYSQL_HOME% -u %user% -p %password% -h %host_name% --local-infile=1 %db_name% < Table_scripts_mysql_rxn.sql >> mysql.log 2>&1
%MYSQL_HOME% -u %user% -p %password% -h %host_name% --local-infile=1 %db_name% < Load_scripts_mysql_rxn_win.sql >> mysql.log 2>&1

echo ----------------------------------------
echo Finished
echo ----------------------------------------
```

### Edit:

> If you are running mysql under Windows and have some special
>   characters in the file that cause problems, you can do this:
>
> <kbd>C:> mysql -e "source batch-file"</kbd>

### Source -> [3.5 Using mysql in Batch Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)

Comment: Double check `set MYSQL_HOME=xxxx` and all other var set... then, try to manually connect from command line (not from batch).. and keep on trying until you find the command that's not working. I don't have mysql installed in my machine rigth now, so I can only guess and gide you, can't give you a direct answer, sorry.

Comment: I ended up decomposing the windows batch file into its elements, and then running equivalent commands from the MySQL command line client.  I am marking yours as the answer because you got me to try the script one line at a time through the command line, even though I was not able to run the commands through cmd.exe.

Comment: I'm glad finally work... And for the answer, well thanks, but the important thing it's find and solve the problem. I also give +1 to the question, don't know why someone gives you -1...